# pod spec lint fails: Unable to create product build directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

When running pod spec lint on my library's podspec file it obviously refers to a non-existing product build root directory. This exhibits itself in various error messages e.g.(running with --verbose):

```
=== BUILD TARGET Pods OF PROJECT Pods WITH THE DEFAULT CONFIGURATION (Release) ===

Check dependencies
error: Unable to create directory: /Volumes/HDD/User Data/me/tmp (Permission denied)
error: Unable to create directory: /Volumes/HDD/User Data/me/tmp (Permission denied)
```

and

```
-> JJIOSLib (0.0.1)
- ERROR | [xcodebuild]  error: Unable to create directory: /Volumes/HDD/User Data/me/tmp (Permission denied)
```

The directory '/Volumes/HDD/User Data/me/' refers to my home directory originating from a different laptop hard drive setup I abandoned a long time ago and I've since been building Xcode projects happily without any harassment from such no longer existing directory.

Nevertheless, CocoaPods is referring to this non-existent directory via some means, so I suspect Xcode is somehow holding on to it. I noticed that 'Build Products Path' (aka SYMROOT) was set to that directory in my target's build settings, so I set it to something meaningful instead. I also found that in the 'IDEApplicationwideBuildSettings' dictionary in ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist SYMROOT was set to '/Volumes/HDD/User Data/me/' so I set it to something meaningful.

But none of this had a positive effect on running pod spec lint.

You could argue that this is a legacy problem of Xcode but I only face this problem when validating the podspec file.

How does CocoaPods derive the build product directory from Xcode? Any help appreciated.